# Sails.js: How to properly handle request parameters/queries to backend?

Tags: http, request, sails.js, waterline

I'm developing an application using Sails.js in the backend, and I'm having trouble validating requests as follows:

I want to block access to certain resources based on an attribute of the logged in user. I have the REST API blueprints enabled, and the shortcut routes disabled. I have the following piece of code:

```
User.findOne()
    .where(query)
    .exec(function(err, user) {
        if (user.team !== req.user.team) {
            return res.view('403');
     }
    return next();
});
```

where `query` is the criteria by which I'd like to do the database search. The idea is that the user can only access the requested user if they're in the same "team".

The problem is that the user can make at least the following kinds of requests to the backend, maybe more (I'm not too experienced with sails, please enlighten me if there's even more types):

```
localhost:1337/user?id=1
```

In this case, the `req` object will have a `req.query` attribute, which I can pass on as `query` as it is. Now, the following kind of request is also possible:

```
localhost:1337/user/1
```

Here `req.query` will be an empty object, while `req.params` is `[ id: '1']`.
Now this is troublesome; if I understand correctly, the the type of `req.params` isn't a JSON object, so I can't pass it as `query` as it is. In addition, I'd have to convert the `id` parameter into Int since it's originally a string for some reason (?).

What I'm asking is if there's a way I may have missed that handles both kinds of requests in the same way, or whether I'll have to take both cases into account in a way like

```
var query = isEmpty(req.query) ? req.params : req.query
```

in which case I'd have to convert `req.params` into something I could pass to the database search and would generally be troublesome and inconvenient. I'd like to know what the best way to handle this situation is.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's funny how right after posting a question you happen to find an answer. Apparently there's a function called `req.allParams()` which "Includes parameters parsed from the url path, the query string, and the request body." according to the official docs. I've no idea how I never bumped into this before, but now I did and it seems to work, so hooray!